# How do I redirect to an external url from Nextjs middleware

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I need help with the following functionality I need to achieve:

1. All my pages are protected, you need to be logged in user to see them
2. We don't want to have a page, where you click on "login" if you are not logged in, we want to redirect you to an oauth sign-in flow right away.
3. Oauth sign in provider is initialised with nextauth
4. A middleware.ts file, that matches all the routes in the app, is responsible to check if you have a session. If no session if found, via the NextAuth API, we take the oauth url and redirect the user to that page with a return url.

However, I cannot find a way to redirect the user to a new page from the middleware file:

```
import { NextApiRequest } from 'next';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import redirect from 'nextjs-redirect';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export async function getCsrfToken(c) {
  const res = await fetch(
    'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/csrf',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        ...(c ? { cookie: c } : {}),
      },
    },

  );
  const { csrfToken } = await res.json();
  return csrfToken;
}

export async function middleware(request: NextApiRequest) {
  const session = await getSession({ req: request });
  if (!session) {
    const signInUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/customOauth';
    const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken(request.cookies);

    const res = await fetch(signInUrl, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ...(request.cookies ? { cookie: request.cookies } : {}),
      },
      // @ts-expect-error
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        csrfToken,
        callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
        json: true,
      }),
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(data.url, request.url));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
};
```

The `return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(data.url, request.url));` gives an `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/html. See <URL> for more details.` error. (as the oauth service runs on a docker)

How can I navigate to external link in the middleware if even possible?